# How to adjust a portfolio's rate of return for contributions and withdrawals?

Tags: portfolio, asset-returns, return

Suppose we have a portfolio with many assets.

Since this portfolio receives monthly contributions and withdrawals, what is the best method to evaluate its global rate of return and avoid computing these contributions as a "profit" and withdrawals as "losses"?

I've already seen some people using abstract entities (e.g.: we may define that we start with 100 entities, and, for a \$100 portfolio, each entity would cost \$1), but I don't know the name of this method in English.

Comment: I think you are probably referring to the "NAV per unit" method of computing Time Weighted Returns. ("units" = what you call "entities"). It is the method used by US Mutual Funds, but is difficult to find clear explanations. I made an attempt here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/44594/how-to-calculate-the-daily-rate-of-return-for-an-actively-traded-account/44596#44596

Comment: Another even  better article is here https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55466/how-to-calculate-the-net-return-of-each-partner-at-different-times where the same method is dicussed for partnership accounting

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @noob2

Comment: vote if you found anyone's comments or answers useful

Answer (score 1):

Usually this would be evaluated using an *internal rate of return*, the rate $r$ which makes the PV of inflows and outflows equal -- assuming a starting inflow of portfolio value at the start date and an outflow as though the portfolio were liquidated at the end date.